# Python list and time

Tags: python, matplotlib, time

I am trying to get the current time and store it when I run a certain OS command ( that runs once a second) so I can plot a graph of time vs output of the command.

When I try to store the current time in a list using: (timeList is an empty list)

```
timeList.append (datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

I get this:

```
[datetime.time(23, 57, 8, 86885), datetime.time(23, 57, 8, 87091), 
datetime.time(23, 57, 9, 90906), datetime.time(23, 57, 10, 95045), 
datetime.time(23, 57, 10, 95110), datetime.time(23, 57, 10, 95148), 
datetime.time(23, 57, 10, 95166), datetime.time(23, 57, 10, 95178)]
```

So in one second, instead of just one list item with current time, I get 2, or 3 items). How do I just capture time at that instant and store it in a list so I can use pyplot to plot this?

Comment: I get only one new entry to the list. When I append the datetime to my empty list, it only contains one entry. Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: It seems your process is running more often than just once a second or else you are adding to the list with no synchronization to the process but to something else

Comment: I had a for loop within which I was calling this and I think thats the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just using it like this, and it works fine (Python 3.3+):

```
from datetime import datetime
time_list = []
time_list.append(datetime.now())
```

If you want to save it or send for other application without converting the types you can think about to use the timestamp rather:

```
from datetime import datetime
time_list = []
time_list.append(datetime.now().timestamp())
```